# C++ 'speechapi_cxx.h': No such file or directory Visual Studio

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, visual-studio-2019, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I'm trying voice to text functions at Visual Studio 2019. I found this code on Microsoft website yet compiler says 'speechapi_cxx.h': No such file or directory.

........................................................................

```
#include <iostream> // cin, cout
#include <speechapi_cxx.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Microsoft::CognitiveServices::Speech;

void recognizeSpeech() {
    // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
    // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
    auto config = SpeechConfig::FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");

    // Creates a speech recognizer
    auto recognizer = SpeechRecognizer::FromConfig(config);
    cout << "Say something...\n";

    // Starts speech recognition, and returns after a single utterance is recognized. The end of a
    // single utterance is determined by listening for silence at the end or until a maximum of 15
    // seconds of audio is processed.  The task returns the recognition text as result. 
    // Note: Since RecognizeOnceAsync() returns only a single utterance, it is suitable only for single
    // shot recognition like command or query. 
    // For long-running multi-utterance recognition, use StartContinuousRecognitionAsync() instead.
    auto result = recognizer->RecognizeOnceAsync().get();

    // Checks result.
    if (result->Reason == ResultReason::RecognizedSpeech) {
        cout << "We recognized: " << result->Text << std::endl;
    }
    else if (result->Reason == ResultReason::NoMatch) {
        cout << "NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (result->Reason == ResultReason::Canceled) {
        auto cancellation = CancellationDetails::FromResult(result);
        cout << "CANCELED: Reason=" << (int)cancellation->Reason << std::endl;

        if (cancellation->Reason == CancellationReason::Error) {
            cout << "CANCELED: ErrorCode= " << (int)cancellation->ErrorCode << std::endl;
            cout << "CANCELED: ErrorDetails=" << cancellation->ErrorDetails << std::endl;
            cout << "CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    recognizeSpeech();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the header included in `#include <speechapi_cxx.h>`. This is because you are missing the necessary libraries. Are you sure you installed the SDK correctly? Next time, it'd be helpful if you provided links to the API you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Speech SDK is not installed on your machine. You may download it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk

Comment: Or not installed correctly, or VS not confugured correctly to find it etc. etc.